# Can't load libpq.dll

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I've an application that works fine on some PCs, but when I try it on a new PC (Windows 10) it raises an error that the libpq.dll can't be loaded.

What dependencies does the libpq.dll have ?. With my application I copy these libraries:

```
libcrypto-1_1.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
libpq.dll
libssl-1_1.dll
```

Do I need to distribute any other library besides those ones ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how your libpq was built.

You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer to check for dlls loaded by your application.

(*view->'show lower pane'* and *view->'lower pane view'->'DLLs'*)